# Python - check several columns and compare string

Tags: python, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe below.

```
       a        b        c
0    one      two    three
1  three      one      two
```

I want to make row 0 and 1 to be treated as a same list? or something, since both row contains 'one', 'two', 'three' even though the order is different.

Should I make a new column which stores all the string from a, b, c column such as,

```
       a        b        c                d
0    one      two    three    one two three
1  three      one      two    three one two
```

and then compare row 0 and 1 of column d?

After this, I want to do .groupby('d') and as a result, 'one two three' and 'three one two' must not be seperated.

I can't think of a way to solve this and need help.

Comment: can you provide an example of a row that should *not* be treated the same?

Comment: a row like one two four should not be treated the same, because row 0, 1 don't have a sting 'four'

Answer (score 1):

The new column you create should be a `tuple`, since lists aren't hashable (`groupby` will fail). So we create the column with `tolist()` first, then we sort it and `transform` it to a `tuple`.

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'a': ['one', 'three'], 'b': ['two', 'one'], 'c': ['three', 'two']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Sorting and transforming...**

```
df['d'] = df.values.tolist()
df['d'] = (    
     df['d'].transform(sorted)
         .transform(tuple)
)
print(df.groupby('d').sum()) # I'm calling sum() just to show groupby working 

# prints only one group:
#                           a       b         c
# d
# (one, three, two)  onethree  twoone  threetwo
```

Comment: sort and transform, get to know new skills, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. The family of methods to split, combine and apply functions to data provided by pandas is really rich. I always keep the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) at hand.

Answer (score 1):

sort the cells in each row before joining to create the grouping string.

use apply with axis=1 to apply this function row-wise.

```
df['d'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.sort_values()), axis=1)

# outputs:

       a    b      c              d
0    one  two  three  one three two
1  three  one    two  one three two
```

grouping by `d` will place both rows in the same group. example:

```
df.groupby('d').agg('count')

               a  b  c
d
one three two  2  2  2
```